# MySQL join or call multiple instantiation methods to run queries in PHP MVC?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I've been building a webapp using MVC design patterns in PHP recently, and I'm undecided over two different ways of getting the same data as I'm not sure which would be better practice / more efficient.

Let's say I am building an app for sorting films and I have two models, one for films and one for genres, and I want to get all the films (including genres) with a certificate of 15 (or your national equivalent).

So this is what I think is the more efficent route to get all of the data from the DB, by using a join to get it all at once:

```
class Film {
    private $db;
    private $title;
    private $genre;

    function __construct($db, $title, $genre) {
        $this->db = $db;
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->genre = $genre;
    }

    static function getFilmsByCert($db, $cert) {
        $records = $this->db->query('SELECT f.title, g.name
             FROM films f
             INNER JOIN genres g ON f.gid = g.id
             WHERE f.cert = ?', array($cert));
        
        $filmList = array();
        foreach($records as $filmData) {
            $genre = new Genre($db, $filmData['g.name']);
            $filmList[] = new Film($db, $filmData['f.title'], $genre);
        }

        return $filmList;
    }
}

class Genre {
    private $db;
    private $name;

    function __construct($db, $name) {
        $this->db = $db;
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

I would then call `Film::getFilmsByCert($db, '15');`.

However, I am aware that a more 'correct' approach in MVC would probably be to use the Genre model to get all of genre data.

So we would add the following to the Genre model:

```
static function getById($db, $gid) {
    $name = $this->db->getval('SELECT name FROM genres WHERE id = ?', array($gid));
    return new Genre($db, $name);
}
```

and getFilmsByCert() would instead be:

```
static function getFilmsByCert($db, $cert) {
    $records = $this->db->query('SELECT title, gid FROM films
                     WHERE cert = ?', array($cert));
    
    $filmList = array();
    foreach($records as $filmData) {
        $genre = Genre::getById($db, $filmData['gid']);
        $filmList[] = new Film($db, $filmData['f.title'], $genre);
    }

    return $filmList;
}
```

Now this more readable and cleaner, but surely when scaled up to many, many different models and properties, this would be much slower as it running more database queries as opposed to the single one in the first example?

Also I am sure the pedants will want to let me know these are actually *domain objects* not models but from what I've read everyone seems to have a slightly different idea of how to implement MVC anyway.

Comment: I agree on every point, and I think the answer is going to come down to “it depends”. The danger of the “oop” way is that you can end up with many db calls that are hidden and nested. But then again, dbs are fast, so don’t commit premature optimization. Option 3 is to create a DAO that is actually a view that does the joins to allow your crud object to see it as a single table.

Comment: @TimMorton thanks for your comment. 'Premature optimization' is an interesting point, I think on that basis I will likely go for option 2 as my app is fairly small. I will also look into the third option you suggested as that could well be a good solution.